# line point checking

Tags: matlab, line

```
plot([x5],[y5],'-',xout_1(1),yout_1(1),'*',xout_1(2),yout_1(2),'*')

x5 =[125  -263]

y5 =[165  -375]

xout_1 =[135.5049    -127.0045]

yout_1 =[  179.6202  -185.7279]
```

This is a scenario of my program.
How will I discard point (135.5049,179.6202) from the line? These value change from each simulation.
Can anyone tell me how to remove that point.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean _"discard"_? MATLAB plots these two points and connects them with a line. At the moment, without one of the points you won't have a line on the plot, you'll have a dot. Maybe you can elaborate on what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I want to remove that point which is not on that line. how will I remove that star point which is at(135.5049,179.6202)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove check if the points fall on the line, do this:

```
slope = (y5(2) - y5(1)) / (x5(2) - x5(1));  %# Slope of main line
thr = 1e-6;                                 %# Threshold to check points
idx = (abs((yout_1 - y5(1)) ./ (xout_1  - x5(1)) - slope) < thr) & ... 
   (xout_1 > min(x5) & xout_1 < max(x5));
```

Now `idx` is a logical vector that has '1's where the point is on the line, and '0' otherwise. To plot these points, use logical indexing:

```
plot(x5, y5, '-', xout_1(idx), yout_1(idx), '*')
```

This will work for any number of points, *i.e* you can add as many points as you want to `xout_1` and `yout_1`, and it'll plot only those falling on the line.

P.S
There is no need in enclosing `x5` and `y5` in brackets, they are already a vector.

Comment: No, In my case some times that point may be on line. It varies for each simulation. How will I do that?

Comment: yes exactly .Want to check if it is on that line .if it on that line  okai. otherwise remove it

Comment: Can you also suggest what to do if the slope is negative?? it is not showing any crossing  even if a point is there.

Comment: @JustinOommen Notice my fix (in the `idx` calculation). It works for zero slope as well (but not for an infinite slope).

Comment: am creating a line using pp=randi([-400 400],2,2) and taking, x= pp(:,1) and y=pp(:,2) then plotting it. Then I want to check whether this line crosses a circle with centre (x1,y1) and radius r.

Comment: Your line, defined by `x5` and `y5` should contain only _two_ points. You can have any number of star-points, defined by `xout_1` and `yout_1` though, and this will plot only those falling on the line.

Comment: in some simulation slope is -ve .

Comment: @JustinOommen I'm not sure how `x`, `y`, `x1`, `y1` and `r` relate to your original question. If you change the details of the question, the answer is no longer relevant. If you have a new (different) question, please post it separately, instead of constantly re-editing this one.